# I have a list of items that have a method, how can I do this method to all items?

Tags: c#, list

Lets say I have a list of items of class AwsomeClass. This class has some properties `string StringA` and `string StringB`. It also has a method `string AwesomeConcatenate()` which (in this basic example) simply returns a new string made up of the two properties.

Is there a way to use a `List<AwesomeClass>` to produce a `List<string>` of the result of AwesomeConcatentate for each item?

I know I can use foreach to do this (and this is what I'm currently doing), but it feels like there ought to be a more concise approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq with `Select` method which *projects each element of a sequence into a new form.*

```
var result = list.Select(ac => ac.AwesomeConcatenate()).ToList()
```

MSDN in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx):

Answer (score 1):

Yep, this is what [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) is for!

```
var stringList = awesomeList.Select(x => x.AwesomeConcatenate()).ToList();
```

[`Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) creates a new sequence by applying the given method to each element in the source sequence.